# How to tell what are my startup files for sh or bash?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, shell

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) question I understand that depending on the operating system `sh` and `bash` behave differently.

Doing `env` and `alias` I can tell that:

Every time I open a OSX Terminal or run `bash` the variable `$SHELL=/bin/bash` runs `source ~/.profile` which calls `source ~/.bashrc`. If I run `$sh` the commands `source ~/.profile` nor `source ~/.bashrc` are not called, hence none of the aliases is defined.

Now on a Linux or UNIX server using `bash` or `sh`:

How can I tell what scripts run at login?

Comment: reading the manual helps: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First identify your shell, as noted in another answer this is simply done via the **ps** command ...

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3360 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 3702 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

To be sure which files are being read you will need to investigate the system which you are logging into. 'bash' shell has many 'if this' then 'do that' otherwise 'do something else' options. To see a full description of what files are sourced see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), but typically the list is ...

- /etc/profile
- $HOME/.bash_profile
- $HOME/.bashrc (if that is configured in the .bash_profile)
- $HOME/.bash_logout (on logout, not login)

For the bourne shell ('sh') it generally goes as follows when logging in

- /etc/profile
- $HOME/.profile

What I like to do on systems I am unfamiliar with is a line in any start up files I am expecting to be read that tests if the standard output is connected to a terminal, and if it is then display the file name. In this example I am using it in the .bash_profile file.

```
[ -t 1 ] && echo "reading .bash_profile"
```

This works for either bash or sh (and a few other derivatives as well). This helps because I know what is being read, when, and if I am getting errors I know which file they came from (errors before the first echoed message are likely from the login process itself, or from the system wide /etc/profile.

Also don't forget you can always create your own bespoke start up files and include them yourself by including them in a file which is already being sourced.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the recommendation. I see that OSX is very different compared to Linux. Lesson of the day: `cat \etc\profile`

Answer (score 1):

1. `/etc/passwd` last field of /etc/passwd will tell you your loggin shell.
2. `ps` running ps will tell you also (and level of shell)

   ```
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
    5802 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
    6292 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
   ```

Comment: thanks, where are `source ~/.profile`,  `source ~/.bashrc` being call with `bash` or `sh`?